# How can someone resend a Facebook friend request the other party accidentally deleted?

Tags: facebook

This seems like such a silly simple thing, I'm shocked that I can't find a solution.

I barely use Facebook at all, but recently someone sent me a friend request that I wanted to accept.  Unfortunately I accidentally hit Delete Request instead.  Now I cannot add them, they cannot add me.  We can message each other, but cannot be "friends" on Facebook.  I cannot find any way to send a second friend request, nor can I send her a friend request (seems like I should be able to, since I was the one who deleted her request originally... but no).

Is there any way for me to send her a friend request, or her to send me another?  I can't find any way to "undo" my deletion either.  This is really annoying... anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/131351653607683):

> When you delete a friend request, the person who sent you the request won't be notified and can't send you another request for one year.

So, she has to wait for one year to send you a friend request. But you can send her friend request. If you are not seeing option to send her friend request then probably she has set the privacy. Ask her to change her privacy settings for adding friends. Instructions are given here: [How do I change who can add me as a friend on Facebook?](https://www.facebook.com/help/217125868312360?helpref=faq_content)

Other than privacy settings, there could be some other reasons also which is mentioned in this Facebook FAQ: [Why can't I add someone as a friend on Facebook?](https://www.facebook.com/help/211926158839933)

If everything looks fine and still you are not able to send her friend request then this block is temporarily and you have to wait for few days or weeks. Facebook sometimes does this kind of blocking for security purpose.

Comment: I'll ask her about her privacy settings... she seems to have everything on her timeline public but maybe friend requests are the exception.

Comment: Seems like that worked... thanks!!